# Create a local copy from a share and keep it in sync

Tags: synchronization, nas

All my files are store on a local server (NAS) and some of my software don't support to work off a network file (not sure why). It leads them to unpredictable behavior. So, I'm looking for a way (tool or technique) to have a local copy of those file on my machine while keeping them in sync with  the server.

Right now, I'm using the copy paste technique which makes a lot of duplicates. Is there any cleaner way?

Thanks